# Module Federation and React Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-context, webpack-module-federation

Is there a simple way of sharing React Context API object (from host to the child modules) ?
Some of the examples seen online are via defining as a node module.
But is there a more simpler way than that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [react-singleton-context](https://github.com/indeedeng/react-singleton-context).

If Yes, Other alternative would be using [promise-based-dynamic-remotes](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#promise-based-dynamic-remotes)
High level view of this approach would be as follows:

- Host Module will load remotes with promise based import.
- Context provided values will be passed to remote module as an arg to module init method.
- Remote module will have to create context with the passed value.

Redux can also be used with similar approach
You can check [here](https://github.com/microsoft/redux-micro-frontend)

Comment: Thanks...So there is no direct way to use the  Context API object...Also, can I find some basic examples of consuming react-singleton-context ?